# Is it possible to have a function which satisfies the following?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, continuity

So basically I would like very much to know if it is possible to have a function which expression has some trigonometric function and that is odd, discontinuous in two points and which derivative intersects the function $t(x) = 2\sin(4x)$ in three distinct points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if } x = -1 \\ 0 & \text{if } x \in {]-1, 1[} \\ 1 & \text{if } x = 1 \end{cases}$$

It's odd because $f(-1) = -1 = - f(1)$ and $f(x) = 0 = -f(x)$ for $x \in {]-1, 1[}$.

It's clearly discontinuous in $-1$ and $1$.

Its derivative $f'$ is defined in $]-1, 1[$ and $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in {]-1, 1[}$.

The equation $t(x) = f'(x)$ is $\sin(4x) = 0$, i.e. $4x = k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $x = k \frac{\pi}{4}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The three points of intersection correspond to $k = -1, 0, 1$, since $\frac{\pi}{4} < 1$ but $\frac{\pi}{2} > 1$.

If you insist that the expression contain trigonometric functions, you can write $f(x) = \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) - 1$ for $x \in {]-1, 1[}$.

Comment: Perfect answer Luca Bressan. Thank you very much for all your efforts. Great work.